# example fails on two different angular rev's (any ideas as why?)

Tags: angularjs

Shaking out promises, got two includes of angular, just for quick prototyping, guessing one will override the other... ok, it's hack, I know.

FACTS:
For some reason only this earlier rev of angular works ok for this code 1.1.5, it fails though for 1.2.20

Other issues in the 1.2.20 rev... If I try to include js from outside an module... that fails to function. Also, html editor yeilds red text error CANNOT FIND HelloCtrl... Don't know why that's happening its right here

Can anyone one determine why this wont work for angular 1.2.20 ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- <script src="./promise-ex2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>  -->

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>       
    <!--  
        FACTS
            for some reason only this earlier rev of angular works for this code
            if I try to include js from outside an module... that fails to function
            also, html editor yeilds red text error CANNOT FIND HelloCtrl... 
                dont know why thats happening its right here

            can anyone one determine why this wont work for angular 1.2.20 ?
     -->

    <script>
    angular.module('myModule', [])

      .factory('HelloWorld', function($q, $timeout) {

        var getMessages = function() {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve(['Hello', 'world']);
          }, 2000);

          return deferred.promise;
        };

        return {
          getMessages: getMessages
        };

      })

      .controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloWorld) {

        $scope.messages = HelloWorld.getMessages();

      });
    </script>    
  </head>

    <body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="HelloCtrl">

        <h1>Messages</h1>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="message in messages">{{ message }}</li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that same code with version 1.2.20 you would have to set `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)` in your `.config`, like this:

```
app.config(function($parseProvider){
  $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true);
})
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/m3ZNqZr1Z5A6dZIXLCxG?p=preview)

That's because promise unwrapping was removed with version 1.2 and it has been completely deprecated with version 1.2.0-rc.3.

You may want to have a look at this document: [Migrating from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration).

> $parse: due to fa6e411d, promise unwrapping has been removed. It has
>   been deprecated since 1.2.0-rc.3. It can no longer be turned on. Two
>   methods have been removed:
>
> ```
>      $parseProvider.unwrapPromises 
>
>      $parseProvider.logPromiseWarnings
> ```